# Continuous textbox verify

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I'm developing a page in ASP.NET with C# and JavaScript and I need to make some method to check  a DropDownList and two TextBoxes if the field is empty and colorful with a background color.

This is necessary for the new users for help they to understand what they need to select or fill.

Comment: So set required and add CSS. HTML5 Validation, plenty of tutorials.

Answer (score 1):

You can do default styling with css

```
select:not(:checked),
input:empty {
  background: lime;
}
```

Comment: That's a good idea, but when I put this in the code, colorful every "input" field include a button. I need only for one drodownlist and two another textboxes.

Comment: you can limit the input styling to textboxes using `input[type="text"]:empty` or omit buttons by `input:not([type="submit"]):empty`. The second will omit input type submit.